# Problema con JavaNullException

Tags: java

Estoy realizando el siguiente problema:

> Elabore un registro llamado Punto que contenga 2 campos: X (Real) y Y
>   (Real), los cuales representan las coordenadas de un punto. Elabore un
>   Registro llamado Triangulo que contenga 3 campos de tipo Punto.
>   Desarrollo el método "void tipoTriangulo(Triangulo T)" que dado un
>   triangulo este imprima el tipo de triangulo.

He realizado esto:

```
    class punto {

    static int x;
    static int y;
}

class triangulo {

    static punto a;
    static punto b;
    static punto c;
}

public class Ejercicio {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        punto c1 = null;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable x");
        c1.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable y");
        c1.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        punto c2 = null;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable x");
        c2.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable y");
        c2.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        punto c3 = null;

        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable x");
        c3.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la variable y");
        c3.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        triangulo PrimerPuntoTriangulo = null;
        PrimerPuntoTriangulo.a.x = (c1.x);
        PrimerPuntoTriangulo.b.y = (c2.y);
        triangulo SegundoPuntoTriangulo = null;
        SegundoPuntoTriangulo.a.x = (c2.x);
        SegundoPuntoTriangulo.b.y = (c2.y);
        triangulo TercerPuntoTriangulo = null;
        TercerPuntoTriangulo.a.x = (c3.x);
        TercerPuntoTriangulo.b.y = (c3.y);

        if (PrimerPuntoTriangulo.equals(SegundoPuntoTriangulo) && SegundoPuntoTriangulo.equals(TercerPuntoTriangulo)) {
            System.out.println("El triangulo es Equilatero");

        } else if (PrimerPuntoTriangulo.equals(SegundoPuntoTriangulo) || PrimerPuntoTriangulo.equals(TercerPuntoTriangulo) || SegundoPuntoTriangulo.equals(TercerPuntoTriangulo)) {
            System.out.println("El triangulo es Isoceles");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El triangulo es Escaleno");

        }

    }
}
```

En esta linea:

```
if (PrimerPuntoTriangulo.equals(SegundoPuntoTriangulo) && SegundoPuntoTriangulo.equals(TercerPuntoTriangulo)) {
```

Netbeans me arroja el siguiente error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Podria alguien ayudarme con esto?

Comment: podrias poner la parte donde declaras las variables de PrimerPuntoTriangulo

Comment: @RaulCacacho Ese es todo el codigo que he desarrollado...

Comment: Tal vez sea porque no ha llamado al constructor de las clases:
`punto c1 = null;` debería ser `punto c1 = new punto();`

Comment: @Bvss12 si son clases entonces cabal como dice  te falta instanciarlas

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona! Ahora lo que tiene es que no me corre como deberia. Es decir, cuando el triangulo deberia ser Equilatero, me dice que es Escaleno. Ando viendo, el porque, cualquier sugerencia de antemano gracias! @Jonathanch

Comment: @RaulCacacho Cual seria la mejor forma de comparar los valores de por ejemplo, PrimerPuntoTriangulo.a.x y SegundoPuntoTriangulo.a.x ?

Comment: @Bvss12 ahi lo estas haciendo bien lo que te falta es abajo de esta linea  es PrimerPuntoTriangulo primero = new PrimerPuntoTriangulo(); y asi para los demas

Comment: @Bvss12 actualicé la respuesta, en realidad estabas realizando más trabajo que el necesario. En este ejercicio no necesitas realizar comparación de objetos si no comparación de las propiedades de los objetos, en este caso los puntos, saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema sucede en este punto como comentas:

```
if (PrimerPuntoTriangulo.equals(SegundoPuntoTriangulo) && SegundoPuntoTriangulo.equals(TercerPuntoTriangulo)) {
```

el problema es que las 3 variables tienen un valor null, por lo tanto no puedes llamar el método `equals()` en una variable con valor null, por eso el error `NullPointerException`,

debes inicializar las variables :

```
   triangulo PrimerPuntoTriangulo = new triangulo();
   ...
   triangulo SegundoPuntoTriangulo = new triangulo();
   ...
   triangulo TercerPuntoTriangulo = new triangulo();
```

lo mismo para las variables:

```
 punto c1 = new punto();
 ...
 punto c2 = new punto();
 ...
 punto c3 = new punto();
 ...
```

---

**Actualización:** En realidad en este ejercicio solo necesitas 1 triangulo y sus 3 puntos, además no necesitas realizar comparación de objetos si no comparación de las propiedades de los objetos, en este caso los puntos. Evita también definir como `static` las variables ya que al instanciar y definir un valor este permanecerá en todas las clases.

Este sería un ejemplo de lo que necesitas:

```
class punto {
    int x;
    int y;
}

class triangulo {
     punto a;
     punto b;
     punto c;
}

public class Ejercicio {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        punto c1 = new punto();
        System.out.println("Punto1, Ingrese la variable x");
        c1.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Punto1, Ingrese la variable y");
        c1.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        punto c2 = new punto();
        System.out.println("Punto2, Ingrese la variable x");
        c2.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Punto2, Ingrese la variable y");
        c2.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        punto c3 = new punto();
        System.out.println("Punto3, Ingrese la variable x");
        c3.x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Punto3, Ingrese la variable y");
        c3.y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();        

        if (((c1.x == c2.x) && (c1.y == c2.y) && (c2.x == c3.x) && (c2.y == c3.y))){
           System.out.println("El triangulo es Equilatero");
        }else if (((c1.x == c2.x) && (c1.y == c2.y) || (c1.x == c3.x) && (c1.y == c3.y) || (c2.x == c3.x) && (c2.y == c3.y))){
            System.out.println("El triangulo es Isoceles");
        } else {
           System.out.println("El triangulo es Escaleno");
        }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al crear la nueva instancia de los objetos no los declares null : `punto c1 = new punto();` igual en triangulo triangulo `PrimerPuntoTriangulo= new triangulo();`

Tienes mal la validación de los objetos,estas validando si los objetos son iguales, no van a ser iguales , deberías validar por los puntos en que seteas la informacion en cada objeto.

Comment: Me podrias dar un ejemplo de validacion mediante puntos? Es que tengo un serio problema con esa validacion.

Comment: Creo que estas entendiendo mal el ejercicio. no tienes que tener 3 triangulos, solo 1 y comprar los puntos del mismo.